# Android Material TextInputEditText не срабатывает часть стиля

Tags: android, android-edittext, material-design

Использую TextInputEditText из Material.

Если я через стиль укажу ограничение в 1 строку, то он не сработает, но если я принудительно установлю в компонент, то он работает нормально.

Почему так происходит?

```
<style name="Login.TextInputEditText">
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">@dimen/spacing_small_8</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">@dimen/spacing_small_8</item>
        //<item name="singleLine">true</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-medium</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/font_large_20</item>
</style>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/tv_login"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_track_order"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/et_login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/login_hint"
            style="@style/Login.TextInputEditText"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:singleLine="true"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: а если через maxLines попробовать?

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, стиль Login

Comment: так же желательно указать `android:inputType="text"`

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov а какая разница, я же в parent его не указывал. А так Login пустой

Comment: @Andrew вместо 1 строчки, будет добавлять 2. К тому же все EditText разные по типу

Comment: @danilshik если бы там был указан inputType, то проблема была бы в нем. Явное указание в parent сильнее, чем неявное через точку. Но если явного нет - работает неявное

Comment: @Andrew а так работает. Хоть singleLine и объявлен Deprecated, и использовать его не стоит (в некоторых случаях все таки стоит, когда MaxLines не так срабатывает https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092961/edittext-maxlines-not-working-user-can-still-input-more-lines-than-set), то почему в этом варианте не срабатывает через Style?

Comment: что-то я запутался что у вас работает а что нет)) я у себя в проекте использую не material edittext а просто edittext и он работает нормально вроде, может конфликтует что-то внутри